# Generate MD5 keys and save in a text file

Tags: batch-file, md5

I'm using the MD5 command line utility which can be obtained from here **http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/**
All i wish to do is to generate the MD5 keys of all the files in a folder and save them in a single file. However, I'm having difficulty to do so even for a single file.
The DOS command that I'm using is this:-

`md5 -n -ooutput_test.txt -i"D:\Tickets&Issues\MD5\data1.csv" "D:\Tickets&Issues\MD5\output_test.csv"`

But i believe all it does is generate the key for the last file and save it in that file itself. Can anyone please help me out with this? I need to get this sorted in less time :(

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Hi Guys! I just figured it out :- The command is :-  
D:\Tickets&Issues\MD5_new>md5 -o"D:\Tickets&Issues\MD5_new\output_test.txt" -i "
D:\Tickets&issues\MD5_new\data3.csv"
Now i need to see if i can save the out put of multiple files into a single file..

Comment: Please make an answer about your findings and post it here to your question.

Comment: The trick here is the spaces, I believe. Notice the whitespace between -i and filename and that there is no space between -o and output file name. That is necessary, i guess,cause if i don't i get me errors like could not open file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a batch file "md5.bat":

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (*) do md5.exe %%f >> output.txt
```

Or if running from the command line:

```
for /r %f in (*) do md5.exe %f >> output.txt
```

Run the bat file inside the directory you want to traverse.

Comment: Getting an error %%f was unexpected at this time.. Any ideas? :(

Comment: Add double quotes around the %%f before the >> to handle long filenames.