# Generate Checksum for a directory in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, md5, checksum

I want to create checksum for directory and I am following the answer given on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228202/generate-md5-keys-and-save-in-a-text-file)

But the problem is that it is creating checksum for each file in the directory and I want to create a checksum for the directory.

I am newbie in this kindly help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: I just want to generate a single checksum based on the content of directory.

Comment: Yeah it is a list of file names along with its date and sizes.
Can you make a change in this:
@echo off
for /r %%f in (*) do md5.exe %%f >> output.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set directory=.
dir /s "%directory%" >"%temp%\filelist"
md5 "%temp%\filelist" >> output.txt
del/q "%temp%\filelist"
```

1. a recursive list of all files in the specified directory is written in a temporary file
   (use `.` for current directory, `%~1` for the first command line parameter)
2. `md5` hash of this file is appended to `output.txt` in current directory
3. the temporary file is deleted

Comment: @Jean-PierreCoetzee, it's linked in the question.

Answer (score -1):

The powershell way would be the following:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . -File  | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Format-Table -Wrap | Out-File -Append <File_Path>
```

or if you only want the file hashes:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object Hash | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders  | Out-File -Append <File_Path>
```